# Seeing more error information for GWT ANT compile

Tags: gwt, ant

I'm working on getting an ANT build working for GWT. My build fails with basically no information-

> [echo-update] (08:27:26)     Compiling gwtp ...
>
> [echo-update] (08:27:30)     Project gwtp updated.
>
> [echo-update] (08:27:43)     build gwt-all
>
> BUILD FAILED
> c:\git\psuite\build\build-gwt.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> c:\git\psuite\build\build-gwt.xml:72: Java returned: 1

The java build portion happens fine with no error here or in eclipse, but the build from java to javascript fails, with basically no error message. Is there something I can do to enable more output? Here's the portion of the ANT build where it's failing.

```
<macrodef name="gwt-compile-js" description="compiles java to javascript">
    <attribute name="module"/>
    <sequential>
        <property name="gwt.args" value="-style ${gwt.compiler.style} -logLevel ${gwt.compiler.loglevel} -compileReport -XsoycDetailed -XdisableCastChecking"/>
        <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" failonerror="true" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${gwt.src.dir}"/>
                <path refid="gwt.project.class.path"/>
            </classpath>
            <jvmarg value="${gwt.compiler.jvmargs}"/>
            <arg line="-war"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.deploy.dir}"/>
            <arg line="-localWorkers ${gwt.compiler.localworkers}"/>
            <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
            <arg line="@{module}"/>
        </java>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The log level is set to ALL, and the style is OBF.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you run your script with verbose option ? http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

Comment: Wow, that did it. I'm sorry for the trouble. New to ANT and didn't see there was a verbose option. What I was using a coworker had marked it as -quiet.